# On html.actionlink click, load a partial view below the link

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, partial-views

Currently in my `view` this is what I have

```
<dt>Credit Saldo</dt>
<dd>@Model.CreditSaldo @Html.ActionLink("Add Credit","AddCredit",routeValues:new{Model.LicenseId})</dd> 
<br/>
<dd>
   <div id="partialDiv"></div>
</dd>
```

Whenever User clicks `Add Credit`, currently it forwards me to new **partial view** (no surprise).

What I want to do is load that partial view in same view, in the div that has Id as **partialdiv**.

Here is the method in **controller**, thats being called when the link is called

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddCredit(Guid licenseid)
{
        var newCredit = new AddCredits();
        return PartialView(newCredit);
}
```

and this is what I've done in partial view

```
@model AdminPortal.Areas.Customer.Models.ViewModels.AddCredits

<div class="input-small">@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.CreditToAdd) <button class="btn-small" type="submit">Add</button></div>
```

How can I load the partial view in same view when the link **"Add Credit"** is clicked?

Edit 1 : **Tried Ajax**

```
<dt>Credit Saldo</dt>
            <dd>@Model.CreditSaldo &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; @Ajax.ActionLink("Add Credit","AddCredit",new{Model.LicenseId}, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "partialDiv"})
            <br/>
            <dd>
               <div id="partialDiv"></div>
            </dd>
```

**Result**: Partial View still loads as new view (not in same view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ajax helpers for that

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Credit","AddCredit",routeValues:new{Model.LicenseId}, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTagetId = "partialDiv"}, new {})
```

In order for these to work, you will need to make sure that you load jquery and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax in your layout.

When including jquery, use a pre 1.9 version or the scripts won't work. If you need a version of jquery 1.9+ add the jquery.migrate package from nuget to your project and load that in your layout too.

Comment: I've tried what you said, still doesn't work. You can see the result in edit 1

Comment: Doesn't this work`  @Scripts.Render("~/js")
         @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)`

Comment: the rendersection just allows views to render content into that area (only full views, no ajax loaded partials use that);  @Scripts just renders out the contents of that bundle.  you will need to check what scripts are in it.  another wait to check, if you use chrome, is look at the network tab and see if it is requesting it via ajax or not

Comment: AjaxOptions missing curly brackets {}, that will result in UpdateTagetId  doesn't exist